# How to pass form data along with angularjs api call using ngresource?

Tags: angularjs, ngresource, mapping-resources

I have my data in json at controller, now i want to send that data to an post api call in service.
service - Article

At my controller :

```
var annotationScripts = {startOffset : range.startOffset , endOffset : range.endOffset};
    Article.post({id: $routeParams.articleId},{data : annotationScripts}
);
```

At my service :

```
factory('Article', function($resource) {
        return $resource('article/:id', {}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', isArray: false },
            post : { method: 'POST', params:{id : '@id'} , data : {@data}, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use $resource out of the box features?

Here's a post example, with a simplified version of what you already have:

Resource service

```
    factory('Article', function($resource) {
      var Article = $resource('article/:id', {id: "@id"});
      return Article;
    });
```

Controller

```
    var article = new Article();
    article.startOffset = range.startOffset;
    article.endOffset = range.endOffset;

    article.$save();
```